# Using a Rails scope as a proxy for the scope of a related object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, geocoding, named-scope

In our application we have two models, Stores and Offers.

Stores are geocoded using the 'geocoder' gem
http://rubydoc.info/gems/geocoder

```
class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
  geocoded_by :address
...
class Offer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :stores
```

The dilemma is that I'd like to be able to search for offers using the 'nearby' scope from geocoder on *Offers*, not just Stores. I'd like to use the Stores the Offers belong to for the nearby search. But I can't seem to get a finder to work correctly

```
  scope :nearby , lambda { |location, radius| 
    joins(:stores).near(location, radius)
  }
```

This doesn't work as the finder is for the *Offers* and doesn't have the available geocoder functions.

Any ideas? I'm basically trying to use the scope of a related object in my new scope. I don't want to geocode the Offers as well, as that's just redundant data. Fairly stumped on this one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just break up the logic: first get all Stores nearby and then load any Offers for those Stores. Psuedo-code:

```
nearby_stores = Store.nearby(...)
offers = Offers.where(:store_id => nearby_stores.collect { |s| s.id })
```

Comment: This does work, but splits it up into two SQL calls and seems inelegant. Still, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think you want:

```
class Offer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :stores
  scope :nearby, lambda { |location, radius| 
      joins(:stores).merge(Store.near(location, radius))
    }
end
```